# Laravel lists concat not showing data (full_name)

Tags: php, laravel

I using Laravel 5.3 in my project, and I am trying to get multiple columns and show the data in a dropdown select element in the view.
I am doing the query like this:

```
$users = User::select(
            DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS full_name, id")
        )->lists('full_name', 'id')->toArray();
```

But this is the data that I get from it:

```
array:6 [▼
  14 => " "
  15 => " "
  16 => " "
  17 => " "
  19 => " "
  22 => " "
]
```

The values are empty for `full_name`, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to avoid the use of the `full_name` keyword like :

```
User::select('id', DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as full"))
      ->lists('full','id')
      ->toArray();
```